# How to migrate MySQL database to SQL Server on a separate machine?

Tags: sql-server, migration, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL datadump file from the database to be moved. From the suggestions I've read so far, most migration tools only work with databases that are hosted on the same server. What steps can I take to convert the MySQL datadump file to an SQL Server database on a separate machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL to migrate data from MySQL into SQL Server.

The steps involved consist of:

1. Mout/Restore/Load the datadump file to a new MySQL server.
2. Use [SSMA for MySQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42657) to migrate to SQL Server.  SSMA does not require MySQL to be installed on the SQL Server machine, however it requires a running database engine to communicate with.